# How to use sed and regex?

Tags: regex, sed

I need to use sed to look for all lines in a file with pattern "[whatever]|[whatever]" so I'm using the following regex:

```
sed '/\"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\"/p' test2.txt
```

But it's not working because in this file is returning something when it shouldn't

```
RTV0031605951US|3160595|20/03/2013|0|"Laurie Graham"|"401"
```

Does anybody know with regex should I use? Thanks in advance

Comment: So what's the issue here?  The line should match as per your description of the desired pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems with your regular expression:

1. `+` is not a metacharacter, so you need to escape it to get its special meaning.
2. Similar issue happens with the pipe. Neither it is a metacharacter, so don't escape it to match it literally.
3. `Sed` by default prints each line that matches, so add `-n` that avoids that, if you already use `/p` that prints it. Otherwise you will have those lines twice in the output.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` will output anything that is a *partial* match.

To match only whole lines that match your regex, add `^` and `$` to the start/end:

```
sed '/^\"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\"$/p' test2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/\B\"[ [:alnum:]]\+\"|\"[ [:alnum:]]\+\"\B/!d' file
```

If you use this in a `sed` script, do not escape double quotes.